# PagerDuty triggering from Windows

Tags: pagerduty

We are looking to trigger notifications to PagerDuty in our system. We have the option of adding calls via PagerDuty API's; however, we would prefer to decouple the code from the external system so that if PagerDuty gets bought by EvilCorp, we can switch without having to go through all the overhead involved with source code changes.

First thought was to use WMI, but research has not yet turned up such an option.

Ideally we would be able to use bits that are built into Windows Server or to use a well-established open source package. Third would be to build our own or just bite the bullet and put it into the code base.

Does such a beast exist?

Comment: You could just use email, which would be easy to point at a different service.

Comment: Use ngDesk instead, its free and has more features https://www.ngdesk.com